# R - Create random subsamples of size n for multiple sample groups

Tags: r

I have a large data set of samples that belong to different groups and differ in the area covered. The structure of the data set is simplified below. I now would like to create pooled samples (Subgroups) for each Group where the area covered by each Subgroup equates to a specified area (e.g. 20). Samples should be allocated randomly and without replacement to each Subgroup and the number of the Subgroup should be listed in a new column at the end of the data frame.

```
SampleID Group Area Subgroup
1          A  1.5        1
2          A  3.8        2
3          A    6        4
4          A  1.9        1
5          A  1.5        3
6          A  4.1        1
7          A  3.7        1
8          A  4.5        3
...                 
300        B  1.2        1
301        B  3.8        1
302        B  4.1        4
303        B  2.6        3
304        B  3.1        5
305        B  3.5        3
306        B  2.1        2
...     
2000       S  2.7        5
...
```

I am currently using the ‘cumsum’ command to create the Subgroups, using the code below.

```
dat <- read.table("Pooling_Test.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
dat$CumArea <- cumsum(dat$Area) 
dat$Diff_CumArea <- c(0, head(cumsum(dat$Area), -1)) 
dat$Sample_Int_1 <- "0"
dat$Sample_End <- "0" 
current.sum <- 0 

for (c in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  current.sum <- current.sum + dat[c, "Area"]
  dat[c, "Diff_CumArea"] <- current.sum  
  if (current.sum >= 20) {
    dat[c, "Sample_Int_1"] <- "1"
    dat[c, "Sample_End"] <- "End"
    current.sum <- 0
dat$Sample_Int_2 <- cumsum(dat$Sample_Int_1)+1
dat$Sample_Final <- dat$Sample_Int_2
for (d in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  if (dat$Sample_End[d] == 'End')
    dat$Subgroup[d] <- dat$Sample_Int_2[d]-1  
  else 0 }
}}

write.csv(dat, file = 'Pooling_Test_Output.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

The resultant data frame shows what I want (see below). However, there are a couple of steps I would like to improve. First, I have problems including a command for choosing samples randomly from each Group, so I currently randomise the order of samples before loading the data frame into R. Secondly, in the output table the Subgroups are numbered consecutively, but I would like to start the Subgroup numbering with 1 for each new Group. Has anybody any advice on how to achieve this?

```
SampleID    Group       CumArea     Subgroups
    1         A           1.5       1
   77         A           4.6       1
    6         A           9.3       1
   43         A          16.4       1
   17         A          19.5       1
   67         A           2.1       2
    4         A           4.3       2
   32         A           8.9       2
  ...         
  300         B           4.5       10
  257         B           6.8       10
  397         B          10.6       10
  344         B          14.5       10
  367         B          16.7       10
  303         B          20.1       10
  306         B           1.5       11
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few functions in the `dplyr` package make this fairly straightforward. You can use `slice` to randomize the data, `group_by` to perform computations at the group level, and `mutate` to create new variables. If you chain the functions together with the `%>%` operator, I believe the solution would look something like this, assuming that you want groups that add up to 20.

```
install.packages("dplyr") #If you haven't used dplyr before
library(dplyr)    

dat %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  slice(sample(1:n())) %>%
  mutate(CumArea = cumsum(Area), SubGroup = ceiling(CumArea / 20))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Your code works perfectly. I have not used the "dplyr" package before but looking at it it seems very powerful.